# Key press events in C# -- Moving a PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am attempting to move a PictureBox(picUser) up and down via the key press events. I am newer to C# and am able to do this via VB. As such I am confused as to what the problem is with the following code:

```
    private void picUser_keyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
        {
            picUser.Top -= 10;
        }
    }
```

There is no "error" with the code, the picturebox just doesn't move.

Comment: Maybe you could describe the problem or provide error logs?

Comment: Good point. I forgot to add that part in after code block. Adjustment has been made

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `PictureBox` has no `KeyDown` event. It has a `PreviewKeyDown` instead and requires the `PictureBox` to have the focus.

I would suggest to use the `KeyDown` of the `form` that host the `PictureBox` instead and use the same exact code:

```
public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyDown);
}

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
     {
         picUser.Top -= 10;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not working because `picUser` does not have the focus, and thus does not receive any key events.

If `picUser` has the focus, your code should work.  However, a better way is probably to set your form's `KeyPreview` property to `true`, and then put your code above into the *form's* `keyDown` event (and set `e.Handled = true` as well, to prevent the key event from being passed on to whichever control does have the focus).