# Easy way for User presses key to set hotkey. Display hotkey text, save virtual key code

Tags: c#, winforms

Not sure if I explained the title good enough, but I would like to have a person press any key and then I can store that key code for later, but more importantly I want visually to show what key they selected. Sort of like a Keyboard setting type thing you get in games.

I was wondering if there was any public classes or something that could ease the troublesome of coding something for each key.

Comment: console? wpf? winforms?

Comment: well the easiest way for you is to control the key press event of a control, the sender will be event args should give you information on the key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a native Win32 control designed explicitly for this purpose, called the [Hot Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775234.aspx) control. You've probably seen it in use in the Windows shell and other applications. That would be the one I recommend that you use, rather than trying to re-invent the wheel yourself.

Unfortunately, WinForms does not provide a wrapper for this control. That means you'll either have to write it yourself or settle for [someone else's implementation of a similar type of control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15085/A-simple-hotkey-selection-control-for-NET).

EDIT: Or use this quickly knocked-together .NET wrapper for the Hot Key control. The entirety of the public interface is the `KeyData` property, which works just like the similarly-named property of the [`KeyEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.aspx) class. The `Text` property (provided by virtue of inheriting from `Control`) doesn't do anything, but could be overloaded to return a pretty-print version of the selected hot key. Additionally, the functionality of the native control's [HKM_SETRULES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775237.aspx) message is left unimplemented; you'll need to add the code yourself if you need that feature.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

internal static class NativeMethods
{
   internal const string HOTKEY_CLASS = "msctls_hotkey32";
   internal const int CS_GLOBALCLASS = 0x4000;

   internal const int WS_CHILD = 0x40000000;
   internal const int WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000;
   internal const int WS_TABSTOP = 0x00010000;
   internal const int WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY = 0x00000004;
   internal const int WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE = 0x00000200;
   internal const int WS_EX_LEFT = 0x00000000;
   internal const int WS_EX_LTRREADING = 0x00000000;
   internal const int WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR = 0x00000000;
   internal const int WS_EX_RIGHT = 0x00001000;
   internal const int WS_EX_RTLREADING = 0x00002000;
   internal const int WS_EX_LEFTSCROLLBAR = 0x00004000;

   internal const int HOTKEYF_SHIFT = 0x01;
   internal const int HOTKEYF_CONTROL = 0x02;
   internal const int HOTKEYF_ALT = 0x04;
   internal const int HOTKEYF_EXT = 0x08;

   internal const int WM_USER = 0x0400;
   internal const int HKM_SETHOTKEY = (WM_USER + 1);
   internal const int HKM_GETHOTKEY = (WM_USER + 2);
   internal const int HKM_SETRULES = (WM_USER + 3);

   [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
   internal static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd,
                                             int msg,
                                             IntPtr wParam,
                                             IntPtr lParam);
}

class HotKey : Control
{
   public HotKey()
   {
      base.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint
                     | ControlStyles.StandardClick
                     | ControlStyles.StandardDoubleClick
                     | ControlStyles.UseTextForAccessibility, false);
      base.SetStyle(ControlStyles.FixedHeight, true);
   }

   public Keys KeyData
   {
      get
      {
         IntPtr retVal = NativeMethods.SendMessage(Handle,
                                                   NativeMethods.HKM_GETHOTKEY,
                                                   IntPtr.Zero,
                                                   IntPtr.Zero);

         Keys keyCode = (Keys)(retVal.ToInt32() & 0xFF);

         int modifierFlags = (retVal.ToInt32() >> 8);
         Keys modifiers = Keys.None;
         if ((modifierFlags & NativeMethods.HOTKEYF_ALT) == NativeMethods.HOTKEYF_ALT)
            modifiers |= Keys.Alt;
         if ((modifierFlags & NativeMethods.HOTKEYF_CONTROL) == NativeMethods.HOTKEYF_CONTROL)
            modifiers |= Keys.Control;
         if ((modifierFlags & NativeMethods.HOTKEYF_SHIFT) == NativeMethods.HOTKEYF_SHIFT)
            modifiers |= Keys.Shift;

         return (keyCode | modifiers);
      }
      set
      {
         Keys keyCode = (value & (~Keys.Alt & ~Keys.Control & ~Keys.Shift));

         int modifierFlags = 0;
         if ((value & Keys.Alt) == Keys.Alt)
            modifierFlags |= NativeMethods.HOTKEYF_ALT;
         if ((value & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control)
            modifierFlags |= NativeMethods.HOTKEYF_CONTROL;
         if ((value & Keys.Shift) == Keys.Shift)
            modifierFlags |= NativeMethods.HOTKEYF_SHIFT;

         NativeMethods.SendMessage(Handle,
                                   NativeMethods.HKM_SETHOTKEY,
                                   (IntPtr)((modifierFlags << 8) | ((int)keyCode & 0xffff)),
                                   IntPtr.Zero);
      }
   }

   protected override CreateParams CreateParams
   {
      get
      {
         CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
         cp.ClassName = NativeMethods.HOTKEY_CLASS;
         cp.ClassStyle = NativeMethods.CS_GLOBALCLASS;
         cp.Style = NativeMethods.WS_CHILD | NativeMethods.WS_VISIBLE | NativeMethods.WS_TABSTOP;
         cp.ExStyle = NativeMethods.WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY | NativeMethods.WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE;
         if (RightToLeft == RightToLeft.No ||
            (RightToLeft == RightToLeft.Inherit && Parent.RightToLeft == RightToLeft.No))
         {
            cp.ExStyle |= NativeMethods.WS_EX_LEFT
                            | NativeMethods.WS_EX_LTRREADING
                            | NativeMethods.WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR;
         }
         else
         {
            cp.ExStyle |= NativeMethods.WS_EX_RIGHT
                           | NativeMethods.WS_EX_RTLREADING
                           | NativeMethods.WS_EX_LEFTSCROLLBAR;
         }
         return cp;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Key press events in C# -- Moving a PictureBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956207/key-press-events-in-c-sharp-moving-a-picturebox).

It mentions the [`Control.KeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx) event.

```
private Keys _lastKeyPressed;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;
}

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something with event keycode
    _lastKeyPressed = e.KeyCode;
}
```

You can also listen to the [`Control.KeyUp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup.aspx) event for when they release the key.