# VB.Net How to get keyboard input and set a variable?

Tags: vb.net

So I'm basically wanting to have a button, that says 'Click here to set bind' then when you click it, it says 'Press Key' and then when the uses presses a key, it sets the a variable to the Value/Enum of the key. E.G if they push LMB it will set it to 1, CapsLock 20, etc...

I've been unable to find anything that helps with this online. I was hoping perhaps someone here could provide some help. Thanks.

Comment: We possibly can provide some help, but we really would like to see you try yourself first.  Please add some code to this question.  Once we see code, even if it doesn't work, we may be able to say something useful.  I think it is just a matter of buttons and events, and those should be easy to find with online documentation.

Comment: I've been trying for quite a while. I've been trying a lot of stuff, but the issue is, the only things I've managed to come up with are defining variables for every single key so that if it sees that 'H' is pressed, then it checks the variable and then the variable contains the key value.

Comment: Actually, that's a much more detailed and better question than the one you asked.  If we had your code, we could have figured out what you actually wanted.  If you don't get good answers, close this question and ask it with your comment as part of the question.  And add some code demonstrating what your problem really is (just do A, B, and C, for example).

Comment: There's a built-in control called the [Hot Key Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775233(v=vs.85).aspx) that might be what you're looking for.  You could place multiple ones on your form, or create a dialog with it to re-use like the OpenFileDialog.  Here's a [C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17501943/2330053) implementation by Cody Gray to start from.  It works quite well...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a event on your form to listen to user key down like this:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyDown(ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnKeyDown(e)

    If (e.KeyCode = Keys.CapsLock) Then
        ' do some thing ...
        Dim value = 20
    ElseIf (e.KeyCode = Keys.Control) Then
        Dim value = 6
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Would I have to define the value for every single key? Or is there a way to grab it through VB?

Comment: No this is just a example to handle any pressed key in a VB form and define a equal value for every key on that method!