# Determine if key was pressed in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, keypress

I want to make a game in C# Windows Forms Application.
(Is it maybe a bad idea? :D)

I need to determine if key was pressed in my timer.
The game is basicly objects like labels or pictureBoxes moving - their location is changed via timer and I need to determine when key is pressed.

I made the same game as a consoleApplication and I wanted to make a "graphic interface" for it, but obviously I can't use this part of my code:

```
if (Console.KeyAvailable)
    {
    ...
    }
```

I am pretty new to c# and programming itself, so I am truly sorry if my question is stupid :-)

Comment: http://csharp.net-informations.com/gui/key-press-cs.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Key press events in C# -- Moving a PictureBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956207/key-press-events-in-c-sharp-moving-a-picturebox)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to implement keyboard shortcuts in a Windows Forms application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400113/best-way-to-implement-keyboard-shortcuts-in-a-windows-forms-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just handle the `KeyPress` event of the control which will have the focus.

With Key press event, the event argument is of type `KeyPressEventArgs` which will give you details of which key is pressed

Comment: Thank you :-) I had no idea there was such a thing as focus.

Comment: @Megabight, glad to know it server yr purpose

Answer (score 0):

You should add this in your Form1 class:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.A) MethodForProcessingTheKey();//for example
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```